Glue Schema registry and Firehose
I want to explore how I can utilize Glue Schema Registry in our application and, if not feasible, what alternative options we have.
Currently, we stream data from DynamoDB tables to an S3-based data lake via DynamoDB streams (Kinesis connector), which then uses Firehose to write to S3.
The metadata for querying by Athena is stored in Glue Tables in S3.
My goal is to employ Glue Schema Registry to manage schema evolution, as there's currently no way to ensure that the structure of Glue Tables aligns with the data streaming from DynamoDB Streams.
The data in S3 is stored in Parquet format, and our application code is in Node.js. I'm aware that Node.js isn't supported with Glue. I'd like more insights on integrating Schema Registry into this design and what other options are available.
